# Vuetifyjs v-text-field prevent focus when click on append-icon

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to create a template for the append icon (multi icon).

When I click on the icon, it will focus on the input field.
How to prevent it?

```
  [1]: https://codepen.io/tructubinh/pen/ExoyMrv?editors=101
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use :append-icon and @click:append. That should work.

```
            <v-text-field
              v-model="password"
              :rules="[rules.required, rules.min]"
              :type="show1 ? 'text' : 'password'"
              name="input-10-1"
              label="Normal with hint text"
              hint="At least 8 characters"
              counter
              :append-icon="show1 ? 'mdi-eye-off' : 'mdi-eye'"
              @click:append="show1 = !show1"
            />
```

### EDIT

If you want to use a template you have to use `.stop` for the mouseup and click event.

```
            <v-text-field
              v-model="password"
              :rules="[rules.required, rules.min]"
              :type="show1 ? 'text' : 'password'"
              name="input-10-1"
              label="Normal with hint text"
              hint="At least 8 characters"
              counter
            >
                <template v-slot:append>
                  <v-icon @mouseup.stop @click.prevent.stop="show1 = !show1"> {{ show1 ? 'mdi-eye-off' : 'mdi-eye' }} </v-icon>
                </template>
            </v-text-field>
```

Comment: sorry, I want to use a template for the append icon.

Answer (score 2):

looks like `append-outer` is the right slot for this, you might need CSS tweaks to get [this](https://codepen.io/xbrin/pen/GRyqaEW) to match your designs

Comment: HI Xavier B.
because I don't want to modify CSS. Is it possible if use append-icon? If don't use a template it is working.

Comment: the list of slots is available there -> https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#slots

Comment: oh ! i found out how to get it done, check the codepen again
https://codepen.io/xbrin/pen/jOYrRdL ( sorry i had to fork again, link updated )

Comment: Could you back to the previous version? I see it is working.

Comment: the previous version with append-outer ? ( https://codepen.io/xbrin/pen/eYyzovG?editors=1010 )

Comment: no, the version with append-outer, but UI same append inner

Comment: right so if you want to be able to use the `append` slot instead of the `append-icon` prop, you can reuse the CSS tweaks i just made in this new pen:
https://codepen.io/xbrin/pen/GRyqaEW

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ref` to access the `v-text-field`'s `blur()` method when clicking on the appended eye icon. This will remove the focus from the field.

Template:

```html
<v-text-field
     v-model="password"
     ...
     ref="myTextField"
>
    <template v-slot:append>
         <v-icon  @click="onClickAppendIcon">
             {{ show1 ? 'mdi-eye-off' : 'mdi-eye' }} 
         </v-icon>
     </template>
</v-text-field>
```

Script:

```js
onClickAppendIcon() {
  this.show1 = !this.show1
  this.$refs.myTextField.blur()
}
```

Comment: Hi @InfectoOne, I want to prevent focus events, use blur it will dirty this input and on mobile, it will show the keyboard and close the keyboard